How to do dua If I am kufr?
I am not religious to Islam.
In view of Abusive father/ Bad step mom I would still want to help.
Is it allowed and possible? How?

To be honest, there is a saying from Allah in Quran that seemingly answers you NO:

مَا دُعَاءُ الْكَافِرِينَ إِلَّا فِي ضَلَالٍ
the prayer of those without Faith is nothing but (futile) wandering (in the mind)
‌
But I guess this will not be an answer to you, as I guess you might have mistaken not being religeous to Islam as kufr. To better reflect what that extract from Quran means, it is suitable to bring the two verse that contains this saying:
لَهُ دَعْوَةُ الْحَقِّ وَ الَّذِينَ يَدْعُونَ مِنْ دُونِهِ لَا يَسْتَجِيبُونَ لَهُمْ بِشَيْءٍ إِلَّا كَبَاسِطِ كَفَّيْهِ إِلَي الْمَاءِ لِيَبْلُغَ فَاهُ وَ مَا هُوَ بِبَالِغِهِ وَ مَا دُعَاءُ الْكَافِرِينَ إِلَّا فِي ضَلَالٍ
For Him (alone) is prayer in Truth: any others that they call upon besides Him hear them no more than if they were to stretch forth their hands for water to reach their mouths but it reaches them not: for the prayer of those without Faith is nothing but (futile) wandering (in the mind).

and

قَالُوا أَوَلَمْ تَكُ تَأْتِيكُمْ رُسُلُكُمْ بِالْبَيِّنَاتِ قَالُوا بَلَيٰ قَالُوا فَادْعُوا وَ مَا دُعَاءُ الْكَافِرِينَ إِلَّا فِي ضَلَالٍ
They will say: 'Did there not come to you your messengers with Clear Signs?' They will say, 'Yes'. They will reply, 'Then pray (as ye like)! But the prayer of those without Faith is nothing but (futile wandering) in (mazes of) error!

If someone says I'm not a believer but rather I like to pray to God for someone, this having request seems to me as a sign of a level of belief. Having faith in Islam has perhaps infinitely many levels, and even Allah commands to the believers to believe!

يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا آمِنُوا بِاللَّهِ وَ رَسُولِهِ وَ الْكِتَابِ الَّذِي نَزَّلَ عَلَيٰ رَسُولِهِ وَ الْكِتَابِ الَّذِي أَنْزَلَ مِنْ قَبْلُ ...
O ye who believe! Believe in Allah and His Messenger, and the scripture which He hath sent to His Messenger and the scripture which He sent to those before ...

